# Multiple NSNotificationCenter Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, nsnotificationcenter, uinavigationitem

In my app in which I'm using storyboards I have mainViewController with MapView inside. At the top of the mainViewController I'm displaying `UIContainerView` from the bottom of the screen with UITableViewController inside. When user click on row I'm sending notification to the mainViewController in purpose of changing map region with animation. The similar notifications are sending when user is selecting specific tableViewCell and also when user tapping on the **DONE** button located in navigationViewController. Everything works fine for me except method called in DONE button method.

> MAIN VIEW CONTROLLER -(void)viewDidLoad method...

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideContainerView:)
                                             name:HideContainerView object:self];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeRegionForUser:)
                                             name:ChangeRegionForUser
                                           object:nil];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideContainerView:)
                                             name:ChangeRegionToInitial
                                           object:nil];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeRegionToFitWearerAnnotations:)
                                             name:ChangeRegionToFitWearerAnnotations
                                           object:nil];
```

> MAIN VIEW CONTROLLER OBSERVERS METHODS:

```
#pragma mark NSNotificationCenter methods
-(void)changeRegionForUser:(NSNotification*)notification
{
NSLog(@"%@",notification.description);
[self zoomToFitUserLocationWithLatitude:-33.861858 longitude:151.210546 andUserInfo:nil];
}
-(void)hideContainerView:(NSNotification*)notification
{   
NSLog(@"%@",notification.description);

[self zoomToFitMapAnnotations:_mainMapView];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"HideContainerAnimation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[_containerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 600, 320, 284)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
-(void)changeRegionToFitWearerAnnotations:(NSNotification*)notification
{
NSLog(@"%@",notification.description);

[self zoomAnnotationsOnMapView:_mainMapView toFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200) animated:YES];
}
```

> TABLE VIEW CONTROLLER (DID-SELECT-ROW-AT-INDEX-PATH METHOD)//It work properly

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ChangeRegionForUser" object:self];
```

> TABLE VIEW CONTROLLER (DONE BUTTON METHOD) //IT DOESN'T WORK

```
-(void)doneButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"HideContainerView" object:self];
}
```

> [image]MY STORYBOARD
>
> IN MAIN VIEW CONTROLLER.H

```
 @interface MainScreenViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate>
extern NSString * const HideContainerView;
extern NSString * const ChangeRegionForUser;
extern NSString * const ChangeRegionToInitial;
extern NSString * const ChangeRegionToFitWearerAnnotations;
```

> IN MAIN VIEW CONTROLLER.M

```
#import "MainScreenViewController.h"
NSString* const HideContainerView = @"HideContainerView";
NSString* const ChangeRegionForUser = @"ChangeRegionForUser";
NSString* const ChangeRegionToInitial = @"ChangeRegionToInitial";
NSString* const ChangeRegionToFitWearerAnnotations =@"ChangeRegionToFitWearerAnnotations";
```

Comment: Can you post your project? Any way the best practice with NSNotificationCenter is addOserver on viewWillAppear and removeObserver on viewWillDisappear of ViewController.

Comment: Sure I know that, but TableViewController is displayed inside UIContainer and is always active. I'm not sure if viewWillDisappear method will change anything in my case. Unfortunately I can't post my project but I can upload some methods if you want...

Comment: In this line ([[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideContainerView:) name:HideContainerView object:self];) is HideContainerView string constant? Where is you did define it?

Comment: It seems to me that it must be something wrong with my IBAction method. I mean doneButtonAction

Answer (score 0):

You are using a string constant `HideContainerView` for the notification name when you add yourself as observer. But when you post the notification you are using a literal string `@"HideContainerView"`. Maybe you are using two different strings there?

Also, I think that you are using `self` as the `object` when you add yourself as an observer. It seems this precludes receiving the notification. From the documentation:

> **notificationSender**
>   The object whose notifications the observer wants to receive; that is, only notifications sent by this sender are delivered to the observer.
>   If you pass nil, the notification center doesn’t use a notification’s sender to decide whether to deliver it to the observer.

Use `nil` instead.

That being said, would it not be better to couple these two controllers more tightly. I think that would be a much more appropriate design. You should send notifications when the sender does not know if the receiver exists or not. But in this case, you know that the receiver exists.

Thus, you should implement a simple delegate protocol, retain a reference to the map view controller and tell it directly what to do.

Comment: No I checked it 100 times, but thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Take a look at my storyboard and try to explain me how can I implement this delegate?

Comment: Implementing delegates is a very common pattern in iOS. You should not have any problems figuring this out. I think it is beyond the scope of this question. (Define the methods in table view controller and set the main view controller as the delegate for both table view and detail view controllers.)

Comment: In which method should I call this delegate ? As you can see container is localised in MainViewController... Can I call delegate from UINavigationItem? I mean method like [self.delegate sendInfoAboutRegion:]

Comment: Trick with using nil instead of self didn't change anything

Comment: What about using singleton? Is there any way to create method which will be able to update MKMapView from other ViewControllers?

Comment: This is not a case for a singleton. BTW, I also noticed that two of your notifications go to the same method `hideContainerView`. Is this intentional?

Comment: YES because I wasn't sure if I made some literal mistake